# Javascript - onclick function being invoked without calling it first

Tags: javascript

I am doing some exercises in javascript with closures, and I have played around with this example, where I was supposed to create buttons and the on clicking them alert their number:

```
function addButtons(numButtons) {   
    for (var i = 0; i < numButtons; i++) {     
    var button = document.createElement('input');     
    button.type = 'button';     
    button.value = 'Button ' + (i + 1);     
    button.onclick = function() {       
        alert('Button ' + (i + 1) + ' clicked');     
    }(i);  
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));   
    } 
}; 

addButtons(5);
```

But, on page load, script is alerting button numbers even before they were created, why is that so?
I have tried with swaping the onclick method for addEventListener like so:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function () {   
        alert('Button ' + (i + 1) + ' clicked');     
}(i));
```

But the result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line

```
button.onclick = function() {       
    alert('Button ' + (i + 1) + ' clicked');     
}(i);
```

Which means that you are creating a `function() {}` and once that function is created, because of the brackets at the end, that function gets executed straight away.

Just change it to:

```
button.onclick = function() {       
    alert('Button ' + (i + 1) + ' clicked');     
};
```

**EDIT:**

By the way, using `i` variable in the click handler will always output the last iteration number. Because in the onclick function you are referring to the i variable, which when the click will occur, will be 6 (since all the iterations will be done at that time).

So if you want to output the button number, you can use:

```
button.onclick = function() {
    // this means the current button that was clicked
    alert(this.value + ' clicked');     
};
```

Comment: Yes, but I added it to attach the current ```ì``` state to it, because this way, it will be number 6 for all buttons.

Comment: See my updated answer. 

And by the way, adding (i) at the end, doesn't actually make it alert the right number. Since the onclick function is executed straight away, the ``i`` variable is still the number of the button. Even if you removed the i, and just called it using (), it would still output the right number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know it wasn't part of my question, but could you explain the difference or more explicitly this solution of the same problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sqbx8tbc/) . What I don't understand in that example is the argument passed to onclick function. Where does that ```x``` comes from? I would be very grateful for that.

Comment: Yes. The functions have variables called ``arguments``. Those are variables that you can pass to the function. Here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/wguq6ron/

Comment: And as you can see in your example, the function is created with an ``x`` argument, ``function (x) { }``, and at the end the function is called and passed the ``i`` variable, ``function (x) { }(i)``, so the value of ``x`` will be the current value of ``i`` (by current, i mean at this point of the loop)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the invocation:

```
button.onclick = function() {       
    alert('Button ' + (i + 1) + ' clicked');     
}(i);   // here: (i)
```

Change to:

```
button.onclick = function() {       
    alert('Button ' + (i + 1) + ' clicked');     
}
```

You are invoking the fn yourself ;)

Comment: But, then it will always be number 6. That is why I added ```i```.

Answer (score 1):

Remove () from the last of the function to avoid self call.

You can add a custom field and get the text from there.Try below:

```js
function addButtons(numButtons) {   
    for (var i = 0; i < numButtons; i++) {     
    var button = document.createElement('input');     
    button.type = 'button';     
    button.value = 'Button ' + (i + 1); 
    button.number=i+1;
    button.onclick = function() {       
        alert(this.number);     
    };  
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));   
    } 
}; 
addButtons(5);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know it wasn't part of my question, but could you explain the difference or more explicitly this solution of the same problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sqbx8tbc/) . What I don't understand in that example is the argument passed to onclick function. Where does that ```x``` comes from? I would be very grateful for that.

Comment: @Leff it is the value of i  passed through (i).

Comment: Oh, of course, thank you so much for the explanation!